# Can we cut some words, some comparator, or it's needed?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> My vision isn't as good (as it used to be).

Can we just say My vision isn't as good? When is it needed and when is it not needed. To me it's easy to infer the meaning based on the context, but I don't know if most native speakers feel that way. Is this "idiomatic"?

Comment: I don't think _as it used to be_ can be omitted, because the speaker might mean _as good as yours_ (or someone else's).  They might say "My vision isn't so good these days", implying the same thing.

Comment: I agree.  If you just say "My vision isn't as good", I would stare at you waiting for you to complete the sentence, and say "...as what?" unless it was already very clear what you were referring to.  If someone said "I have 20/20 vision!" and you said "My vision isn't as good", it would be clear what you mean, but not without any context.